# what does tenant refer to in Adobe CQ

Tags: adobe, aem

i have just started learning adobe cq and i see terms(and api) like tenant being referred to.
what does a tenant refer to in CQ terminology.
also is there any good tutorial any one can refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Apache Sling Tenant supports this sort of model: one CQ5 instance provided by a hosting service, multiple sites for multiple customers of the service using the same instance, each customer sees and controls only his own content.  There's not much documentation that I can find.  There is a [draft design](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SLING/Multitenancy+Support) page for the feature.  I doubt that CQ5 fully supports the feature.